# How to introduce a symbol for the derivative as a symbol with a point on top?

Tags: writing, term-rewriting

I am making images in Mma for an article. In a FrameLabel I need to show a text containing a derivative in form of the letter X with a point on top:

[image]

I found a special button in Palette "Writing Assistant" to introduce a letter with a double point on top. But I need only one point, and this I cannot find.
Any idea?

Comment: `Style[OverDot[X], FontFamily -> "Times", Italic, 22, Red]` ?

Comment: On the `Writing Assistant` palette, `Typesetting` section, `Typesetting Forms` tab, row 2, column 1.

Comment: `Overscript[]` may be usefull too  (`Overscript["X", "\[FilledCircle]"]`)

Comment: There is also a keyboard short cut to move to the overscript position: type the X, then type ctrl-7, then type the dot.

Answer (score 2):

I thank very much all of you for the ideas. Here I give the solution I found on the basis of the suggestion of @andre314 that I find to look best on the image

```
Style[Overscript["X", 
  Row[{Spacer[10], Style[".", 20]}]], 15, Italic, Black, 
 FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

returning this:

[image]

My image looks now as follows:

[image]

Thank you very much once more.